# Is there a BP with available smart-contracts that we can simply run without submitting?

Tags: smart-contract, block-producer

Submitting a smart contracts to different BPs gives me different errors.

Would there be a BP with ready-to-run smart-contracts (which are found in a /contracts directory) that can be executed by EOS holders ?

If yes, what do we need to do to execute ?

Comment: can you provide some examples of what you're trying to do? what do you mean by "submitting a smart contract"?

Comment: cleos set contract [OPTIONS] account contract-dir [wast-file] [abi-file];  Gives Error 3090004: missing required authority when BP endpoint is used, but works when localhost endpoint is used. In other words, I want a BP to execute a contract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `cleos set contract [OPTIONS] account contract-dir [wast-file] [abi-file]`; Gives Error 3090004: missing required authority when BP endpoint is used

Sounds like you are trying to deploy a smart contract with the permissions of an account you don't have on the main net. E.g. trying to deploy a contract at `eosio.token` which is something you'll have the permissions to on a test net but wouldn't on the main net.

If you want to deploy you must have the private key to the account you're using. To check you can run `cleos get account` look up the public keys which own the account, then check what keys you have in your wallet with `cleos wallet keys`

If you're trying to deploy for testing purposes, I recommend using the Jungle testnet or your local testnet.

You shouldn't find any difference when deploying to different BP's, they're all meant to do the same job.

Comment: Exactly, but the problem is, I have already imported the private key to a wallet (when doing the wallet keys, the pub key is displayed) and I am still getting an error. I will accept this as an answer, but it does not solve the issue I have.

Comment: Haha I appreciate it but you're not expected to accept this as best answer if it doesn't solve the issue! Can you confirm that you have this account existing on the main net, should I go on the main net and do a `cleos get account *Your account name you registered with 12 characters*` it will let the public keys, and in your wallet you have the private keys for them?

Comment: yes, the account is on the main net and private keys are in the wallet.  Unfortunately I do not have an access to a VM this moment to confirm all details...

Answer (score 0):

The problem of getting error is about that you missed certain account which is used for authorized your "submission". 
I could suggest you to create an account on http://jungle.cryptolions.io which then gives you 200 EOS on the testnet for test. You will then use this account for do your job on that testnet for submission your own contract.