# Trying to re-deploy the contract gives Assert Exception (10)

Tags: cleos, authorization

I am trying to re-deploy the contract by doing:

```
cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io set contract gazaomauaaae /eos-master/contracts/some.contract /eos-master/contracts/some.contract/some.contract.wast  /eos-master/contracts/some.contract/some.contract.abi
```

It worked the first time. Every next time I repeat (with a compiling step) I am getting this error:

> 420869ms thread-0   main.cpp:2712                 main
>   ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)

How do I remove the contract(s) or re-deploy without getting an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple.

Deploy the Hello example with the contract name gazaomauaaae.

Deploy your original contract, again as gazaomauaaae.

DONE.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in check when deploying a contract to refuse to deploy the contract if it hasn't changed.  This can be problematic when you are making changes to the ABI as changes to it don't count as changes to the contract.

For debugging purposes, my typical workaround is to have some innocuous statement in the contract (usually a `print` statement) that I can comment or uncomment as necessary to force the compiled code to change.